# creating a generator in a threaded manner

Tags: python, multithreading

How Can I create a thread generator to give output as soon as the first finishes,i.e I have `client.decode` which does some `nltk` then gives back a string for each link in links it will give a different string (regardless of link)

```
from scrapy.http import JsonRequest
import nltk,json,os

class Hd3Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hd3'     
    def start_requests(self):
        url = get_url('http://httpbin.org/anything')
        for di in links:
            decoded_str = client.decode(type=4,) #function that takes about 40-100 sec
            data = {'decoded_str': decoded_str}} 
            yield JsonRequest(url, data=data, callback=self.parse,meta={'original':di['enc']})

    def parse(self,response):
        #rest of code
```

what I want is to speed things up,instead of solving one at a time in the for loop I would like to get the output of function as soon as they are produced

Comment: If you have multiple generators running at the same time (in different threads), they should all `put` their "output" into a shared `Queue` and there should be some other thread (perhaps the main one) which continuously checks the queue's contents and `get` the things being put into it but the generators. This assumes that the rest of the code the generators are executing is also thread-safe.